# Mathematical approach in the calculation of work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a statement that says:

> In doing a job, Emilio and Sebastián take 2 months, Emilio and Rolando take
>   3 months, Sebastián and Rolando take 6 months. So, how long will the
>   three in doing this work, if they work together?

I tried to make a system of equations, but I came up with an erroneous result.

I tried to solve with reasons, but I did not get anywhere. It is also assumed, that I should solve this in less than 2 minutes, but I have been trying for 45 minutes and I can not find the form, how could I then solve it?

I also know the equation to state the time it will take, which is: 
$\frac{1}{t} = \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{r} + \frac {1}{e}$, 
where $ t = $ total time among those, $ s = $ Sebastian's time, $ e = $ Emilio's time, $ r = $ Rolando's time.

Comment: "Emilio and Sebastián take 2 months" means $\frac1e+\frac1s=\frac12$. Also, i would suggest solving for $\frac1e,\frac1s,\frac1r$ as the unknowns instead of $e,s,r$. It's a lot easier.

Comment: Could one of them be very lazy ?

Comment: As mentioned by Arthur, you could take the reciprocals of the time taken, add them up and divide them by two.

Comment: Helix, why he did that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**method 1:**

let rates of working of Emilio , Sebastian and Rolando be E,S and R respectively

$E+S=\dfrac{1}{2} $

$S+R=\dfrac{1}{6}$

$R+E=\dfrac{1}{3}$

adding all of them

$2(E+S+R)=1$

$E+S+R=\dfrac{1}{2}$

so, if they (all three) work togeather the work will be finished in $2$ months

**alternative method:**

i am taking work in terms of "days " not in "months"

assume total units of work = $LCM (2\times 30,6\times30,3\times30)=6 \times 30$ units

since $E$ and $S$ together finish work in $60 $ days,work done by them in a day=$180/60=3 unit/day$

$S$ and $R$ together finish work in $180 $ days,work done by them in a day=$180/180=1 unit/day$

$R$ and $E$ together finish work in $90$ days,work done by them in a day=$180/90=2 unit/day$

If they all work togeather work done by them in a day =$3\dfrac{units} {day}$

so, all of them will together finish work of $180$ units in =$ \dfrac{180}{3} $days=$2$ months

Comment: My problem to understand the first method, is just after: `adding all of them`, How did you manage to put them together? Where did that $ 2 $ come from? Could you explain the reasoning or method you used?

Comment: The same with the second method, my problem of not understanding it is right in the step: `If they all work togeather work done by them in a day`, how did you get your work together?

Comment: Help me @veeresh

Comment: His answer already tells you the answer

Answer (score 4):

You can write, 
$$\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{s}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{6}$$

From these series of simultaneous equations, you can easily get your desired answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not such an easy thing. The important thing to notice is that Rolando does no work, in which case $1/r$ would have to equal zero. I assume this is what the asker meant when they mention an erroneous result. Veeresh Pandey had another answer that focused on *rates* rather than completion times that avoids this issue, but unfortunately he's deleted it.

Comment: thanks a lot @ T . Bongers.

Comment: @T.Bongers would it then seem more understandable if i replace 1/r with r and each corresponding with the reciprocal as veeresh has done?

Comment: Ah yes, [parallel impedances](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/resis.html#c3).

Comment: @T.Bongers I would appreciate, if you tell me how you got the conclusion that rolando does not work.

Comment: I already tried that, without getting anything. I did not put what I tried because none of my developments came to anything concrete, just reasons and a quadratic equation. @QuIcKmAtHs

Comment: help me @QuIcKmAtHs